# Use result of checkbox in a query

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have a search form in which a user will select search criteria.

```
<form action="show_time_search3.php" method="post">
    <p><strong>From Date</strong> (YYYY-MM-DD): <input type="datetime" name="day" size="10" maxlength="10" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['day'])) echo $_POST['day']; ?>" /></p>
    <p><strong>To Date </strong> (YYYY-MM-DD): <input type="datetime" name="day2" size="10" maxlength="10" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['day2'])) echo $_POST['day2']; ?>" /></p>  
    <p><strong>Type:</strong>&nbsp(Click on one or more)&nbsp
    <strong>CL&nbsp</strong><input type=checkbox name=type[] size="2" maxlength="2" value=CL>&nbsp &nbsp
    <strong>CO&nbsp</strong><input type=checkbox name=type[] size="2" maxlength="2" value=CO>&nbsp &nbsp
    <strong>CS&nbsp</strong><input type=checkbox name=type[] size="2" maxlength="2" value=CS>&nbsp &nbsp
    <p><strong>Student ID</strong>: <input type="text" name="studentid" size="4" maxlength="4" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['studentid'])) echo $_POST['studentid']; ?>"  /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

I wish to include the result of the checkbox called type in my query as follows:

```
// Make the query:
$q = "SELECT (TIMEDIFF(endtime, startime)) as difference,
timeid, 
DATE_FORMAT(day, '%b %d, %Y') as dia, 
DATE_FORMAT(startime, '%r') as start, 
DATE_FORMAT(endtime, '%r') as end, 
type, 
studentid from time 
WHERE studentid='$id' AND type=$type AND day>='$day' and day<='$day2'";

$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.
```

I have tried to implode but get a convert array error message.

I just want to include the type array results in my query.

Comment: Just checking, do you want the user to be able to select more that one checkbox or did you mean to use radio buttons?

Comment: I used a checkbox because I want the user to be able to select more than one checkbox value if they are looking for more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the user to be able to select multiple types

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="CL" checked="checked" />
```

will result in `$_POST['type'][0]` existing with the value CL.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="CL" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="CO" checked="checked" />
```

will result in `$_POST['type'][0]='CL'` and `$_POST['type'][1]='CO'`

As long as you check `isset($_POST['type'])` to avoid errors, you can implode the array

```
$where="WHERE studentid='$id'
    AND type IN ('".implode("','", $_POST['type'])."')
    AND day>='$day' and day<='$day2'";
```

should work, giving

```
type IN ('CL', 'CO')
```

**but you really need to sanitize those $_POSTs**.

Comment: I used the above code and get:
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE) in     C:\xampp\htdocs\Stupay\show_time_search3.php on line 39

Line 39 is the 
    IN ('".implode("','" $_POST['type'])."')

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, but you could have should have been able to look at where that error occurred and, if not familiar with implode, looked the function up, and been able to see what was wrong.

Comment: Will look it up. What was the typo?

Comment: I have tried different variations of implode to no avail. I keep getting errors     like Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1     to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Stupay    \show_time_search3.php on line 47. Examples from books and online just do not work. This is very frustrating.

Comment: `expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given` means your query isn't right. What is the generated query?

Comment: Solved!!! Thank You, Thank You Popnoodles! Your update with the missing comma and a few other characters worked!!!